# Why is my footer at the top of my page?

Tags: html, css

Firstly, I was used

```
#copyright {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 50px
}

footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 50px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Which worked fine until I tested my site on a smaller screen and realised the footers were overlapping the content. So then I tried setting `html` and `body` height to `100%` and also setting my `wrapper` to min height `100%` and placing the footer underneath, in hopes of a more relative footer. But now it is stuck at the top, what is causing this ?

```css
#wrapper {
 display: block;
   position: fixed;
   text-align: center;
   min-height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}

#header p {
 font-size: 2em;
 margin: 0;
}

#header ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

#header ul li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 20px 20px;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin: 0 30px;

}


#copyright {
 position: relative;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 0.8em;
}

#footer {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 15px;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 0.8em;
}

#footer ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

#footer ul li {
 display: inline;
 margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<p>Pavel Design</p>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="contentwrapper">
<div id="content">
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tempus     imperdiet nulla scelerisque bibendum. Praesent eu tempus dolor, vel venenatis purus.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<footer id="footer">
    <ul>
 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
 <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
 <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="mailto:info@pavel.co.nz">info@pavel.co.nz</a></li>
    </ul>
<p>© Pavel Design 2016  |  Photography, design and website construction by Pavel Design 2016</p>
</footer>
```

EDIT:

My wrapper uses fixed position so that I can assign `top: 0` `bottom: 0` and so on, because I use a background image that covers the whole screen, when I only use `min-height` and `min-width` the background image doesn't cover the whole screen, instead it leaves a small white border around the outside of the page

Comment: because `wrapper` and all its contents are `fixed` position...

Comment: Here is some tips to check for future: why does it stay here, not there? So, you can think about: `place`, `panel`, `frame`,... All of them relate to `position`. So, check all `position` to solve the problem. Good luck.

Comment: try mine , it works !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to give two footers and also you don't need to give `id="footer"`
as HTML5 already provided you the tag, try this if it works for you

Check this demo here [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gs22bob/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<p>Pavel Design</p>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="contentwrapper">
<div id="content">
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tempus     imperdiet nulla scelerisque bibendum. Praesent eu tempus dolor, vel venenatis purus.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<footer>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:info@pavel.co.nz">info@pavel.co.nz</a></li>
        </ul>
    <p>© Pavel Design 2016  |  Photography, design and website construction by Pavel Design 2016</p>
    </footer>
```

**CSS**

```
 #wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#header p {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
}

#header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#header ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 30px;

}
footer {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 2%;
  height: 50 width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  bottom: 0;
}
footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
footer ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: can you explain why yours worked? What changes you have made? Why his didn't work?  Thanks

Comment: @Nguaial, he was using position relative for the footer but is should be fixed according to his requirements

Answer (score 0):

this works

```css
#wrapper {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10%// or some other value depending on your requirements 

}
#header p {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
}
#header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#header ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 30px;
}
#copyright {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 50 width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  bottom: 0;
}
#footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#footer ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <p>Pavel Design</p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="contentwrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tempus imperdiet nulla scelerisque bibendum. Praesent eu tempus dolor, vel venenatis purus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer id="footer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="mailto:info@pavel.co.nz">info@pavel.co.nz</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>

<footer id="copyright">
  <p>© Pavel Design 2016 | Photography, design and website construction by Pavel Design 2016</p>
</footer>
```

the issue happens because you set the wrappers position to `fixed` and the footers position to `relative`. As for the "overlapping" issue set a `margin-bottom:10%` to the wrapper this will make sure the wrapper keeps on scrolling till all of the wrapper content is visible

Comment: This now causes my initial problem of having the footer overlap the content now. instead of being stuck at the top of the page

Comment: it still has the same issue when i run the code snippet

Comment: could you please elaborate your problem? as far as i know a footer should be stuck at the bottom if it has to be stuck any way

Comment: Okay so first of all I had my footer stuck at the bottom. but when I would scroll down, the footer would cover my content. Then my second problem was the footer was at the top of the page. What I would like to happen is that when I scroll down, the footer also scrolls down so it doesn't cover the page.

Comment: adding a `margin-bottom:10%` or some other `margin-bottom` value fixes your `the footer would cover my content.` problem